# Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory in express

Tags: express

Learning express in the meantime I am unable to solve this error which says  Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory while my folder structure looks like this

[image]

I tried setting the path nothing works

```
const pathDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '../public')
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views')
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/partials')

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, viewsPath));
hbs.registerPartials(partialsPath)

app.use(express.static(pathDirectory))
```

The page of index.hbs should be displayed

Answer (score 1):

Try including

```
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
```

after `express.static` method.

That would help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply cut your views folder and paste it inside the src.
You can also write
`app.set('views', '../templates/views')`

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, viewsPath));
```

try:

```
app.set('views','viewsPath');
```

Answer (score 0):

While you run it on the terminal change your directory to webserver, then run the app.js file using

```
node src/app.js
```

I tried this and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy this and try

```
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname , "../templates/partials");  


// to set the view engine
app.set("view engine","hbs");
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname , '../templates/views'));
hbs.registerPartials(partialsPath);
```